# How to preload next page in BottomNavigationBar flutter?

Tags: dart, tabs, flutter, preload, tabview

I'm new in Flutter. I'm using BottomNavigationBar to control 3 pages. But I want to preload the next tab before switching. How can I get it? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you be more specific, please? What do you display in these pages? Also, provide code.

Comment: In the next tab, it has a GoogleMap. I need it to be preloaded and available.

Comment: You can use `FutureBuilder`.